# Linking values to drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I need to link a set of values to different drop down lists definitions. I know how to define a drop down list and recall it in the worksheet, but can't figure out how to associate/link it to a set of values.

What I need is something like this given the drop down list(s)

```
 [High Risk]
 [Low Risk ]
```

When I select High Risk from the drop-down list I need the following values to update in the cells below

```
A1    [High Risk]  #Choosing high risk from drop-down list links the following values for A2-A4
A2       30
A3       50
A4       20
```

Changing the list name to Low Risk I need the values to chage to the numbers below:

```
A1    [Low Risk]  #Choosing low risk from drop-down list changes values for A2-A4
A2       30
A3       30
A4       40
```

I have tried playing under Developer options Combo Box feature, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in A2-A4:

```
=IF($A$1="High Risk",30,(IF($A$1="Low Risk",50,"No Value in A1")))
```

Change the values as needed.